# How to programmatically select multiple options with Chosen.JS multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I'm having trouble figuring out how to select multiple values in a multiple select programmatically, with chosenJS/chosen.js and still have the values binded to my ng-model (angularJS).

Case: I have a list of users from which some are already saved on the current project. I want to show these users as selected (but i have no idea how).

I have tried finding the indexs of the users that i want pre-selected and make them "selected" like this:

```
$('.chzn-container-multi').val(0).trigger('liszt:updated');
$('.chzn-container-multi').val(1).trigger('liszt:updated');
$('.chzn-container-multi').val(2).trigger('liszt:updated');
```

but this only selects the last one.

Any help would be much appreciated !

**EDIT**

With help from #Marek Kowalski i was able to select the values in my list, but it wasn't applied to the ng-model connected with my dropdown, anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Look at this directive https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Selecting multiple values and updating the chosen can be done via this one-liner

For version < 1.0

```
$('.chzn-container-multi').val([0,1,2]).trigger('liszt:updated');
```

OR for version > 1.0

```
$('.chzn-container-multi').val([0,1,2]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: This one works. Passing the array of values, instead of different values multiple times.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal: Well if you are passing different values at different times then only the last one will be selected. That's exactly what OP wanted to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the recommended way of doing it, but the solution which works for me is to manually change the selected="selected" attributes on the options and than trigger the "liszt:updated" event. To select first 3 options use the following code:

```
$('select option:nth-child(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('select option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('select option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('select').trigger('liszt:updated');
// since version 1.0 the event name is changed to
$('select').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: I tried using you'r way, but even though i managed to show some of my 'users' as selected it didn't fully solve my problem.

I am using angularJS, and with an ordinary select using angularJS and ChosenJS whenever i select something manually it also updates my ngModel, but it does'nt update when using the multiple selector.

I've updated my question above using you'r example as guidance.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware the question is about angularJS. I didn't have an occasion to take a look at it yet, so I can't help here. Good luck!